# Merge and sort two object arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays and depending on the element's position in the array it receives a value. Both arrays contain the same elements, but at different positions. I would like to calculate the value for each element, merge the arrays into a single array, and sort the new array.

The only idea I can think of is to turn my initial arrays into arrays of objects, merge those, sort by object value, then map that order into a new array.

```
var ranks = [],
    objArray1 = [],
    objArray2 = [];

// 'aaa' = 5, 'bbb' = 4, 'ddd' = 3, 'eee' = 2, 'ccc' = 1
var array1 = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd', 'eee', 'ccc'];

// 'ddd' = 5, 'ccc' = 4, 'aaa' = 3, 'bbb' = 2, 'eee' = 1
var array2 = ['ddd', 'ccc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'eee'];

for (var i = 0, x = 5; i < 5; x--, i++) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[array1[i]] = x;
  objArray1.push(obj);
}

for (var i = 0, x = 5; i < 5; x--, i++) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[array2[i]] = x;
  objArray2.push(obj);
}

// combine both object arrays, match keys, but add values
// should output ranks =[{aaa: 8}, {bbb: 6}, {ccc: 5}, {ddd: 8}, {eee: 3}]

// then sort based on value
// should output ranks = [{aaa: 8}, {ddd: 8}, {bbb: 6}, {ccc: 5}, {eee: 3}]

// then copy keys over to new array while keeping position
// should output var final = ['aaa', 'ddd', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'eee']
```

Comment: This looks like a homework/interview problem?

Comment: You just wanna sort the elements by their sum over both arrays?

Comment: what is an expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip the part with new temporary arrays with objects and take just an object for counting and then take the sorted keys as result.

```js
var array1 = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd', 'eee', 'ccc'],
    array2 = ['ddd', 'ccc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'eee'],
    temp = Object.create(null),
    result;

[array1, array2].forEach(a => a.forEach((k, i) => temp[k] = (temp[k] || 0) - i));
result = Object.keys(temp).sort((a, b) => temp[b] - temp[a]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey that's really clever! Many thanks! The solution I was working on was just a mess of loops, this is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` to create object and then use `sort` on `Object.keys`.

```js
const array1 = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd', 'eee', 'ccc'];
const array2 = ['ddd', 'ccc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'eee'];
const n = array1.length;

const r = array1.reduce((r, e, i) => (r[e] = n - i + n - array2.indexOf(e), r), {})
const result = Object.keys(r).sort((a, b) => r[b] - r[a])
console.log(result)
```