# Merge / Replace object in array with same Id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays, and I try to merge the 2 arrays based on their id, and the sequence of the array must be same as the first array

```
array1: [
{id: student1, name: 'Jacky', course: ''},
{id: student2, name: 'Taylor', course: ''},
{id: student3, name: 'David', course: ''},
{id: student4, name: 'Aisy', course: ''},
{id: student5, name: 'Micky', course: ''}
];
```

and

```
array2: [
{id: student1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'science'},
{id: student2, name: 'Taylor', course: 'biology'},
{id: student1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'math'},
{id: student4, name: 'Aisy', course: 'chemistry'},
{id: student1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'history'},
];
```

I want the result be like

```
array:[
{id: student1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'science'},
{id: student1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'math'},
{id: student1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'history'},
{id: student2, name: 'Taylor', course: 'biology'},
{id: student3, name: 'David', course: ''},
{id: student4, name: 'Aisy', course: 'chemistry'},
{id: student5, name: 'Micky', course: ''}
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge and sort two object arrays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997836/merge-and-sort-two-object-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Can the first array contain duplicates? Can the second array contain IDs which are not in the first array? Please add constraints, if any, without which, this question is too broad to answer. And most important, please add what you've already tried.

Comment: @31piy, yes, the first array can contain duplicates like the second array Jacky's records, second array will not contain id which not in first array

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this:

```
    const result = [];
    array1.forEach(a1 => {
      result.push(a1);
      array2.forEach(a2 => {
        if (a1.id === a2.id) {
          result.push(a2);
        }
      });
    });
```

or just one line code:

```
const result =([...array1,...array2]).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Last based on the reference from above, I found a way thats works for my situation

```
let _newArray = [];
    array1.forEach(element => {
      const temp = array2.filter(x => x.id === element.id);
      const temp2 = temp.filter(
        x => !_newArray.find(y => y.id === x.id && y.name === x.name)
      );
      if (temp.length > 0) {
        _newArray = [..._newArray, ...temp2];
      } else {
        _newArray.push(element);
      }
    });

console.log(_newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce`, `filter` methods in combination with `spread syntax`.

```js
var array1 = [ {id: 1, name: 'Jacky', course: ''}, {id: 2, name: 'Taylor', course: ''}, {id: 3, name: 'David', course: ''}, {id: 4, name: 'Aisy', course: ''}, {id: 5, name: 'Micky', course: ''} ], array2= [ {id: 1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'science'}, {id: 2, name: 'Taylor', course: 'biology'}, {id: 1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'math'}, {id: 4, name: 'Aisy', course: 'chemistry'}, {id: 1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'history'}, ];
let arr = array1.reduce((arr, item) => {
  let itemsFromSecondArray = array2.filter(({id}) => id == item.id);
  if(itemsFromSecondArray.length){
    arr.push(...itemsFromSecondArray);
  } else arr.push(item);
  return arr;
}, []);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use **spread**, **filter** and **forEach** feature.

```js
    let array1 = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Jacky', course: ''},
    {id: 2, name: 'Taylor', course: ''},
    {id: 3, name: 'David', course: ''},
    {id: 4, name: 'Aisy', course: ''},
    {id: 5, name: 'Micky', course: ''}
    ]

    let array2 = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'science'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Taylor', course: 'biology'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'math'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Aisy', course: 'chemistry'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Jacky', course: 'history'},
    ]

    let r = [];
    array1.forEach(course => {
      let arr = array2.filter(c => c.name === course.name);
      if (arr.length > 0) {
     r = [...r, ...arr];
      } else {
        r.push(course)
      }
    });
    console.log(r);
```